# how to make VS2017 output window show only errors

Tags: visual-studio

I have the VS 2017 Community version and I am trying to set the debug output window to show only errors and with no warnings (I don't care about them)
Thanks

Comment: Errors and warnigns might appear in debug output from both the code itself or by visual studio (such as when thread is exited, modules are loaded, etc.). Could you please add more clarification on that to make it easeir to help you?

Comment: I have tons of this kind of warnings "1>c:\s\example.cpp(2669): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data" which i don't want to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help with what you are trying to do.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Direct from microsoft and has step by step instructions to disable warnings.